# how to grant all revoked privileges for admin

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

i have accidentally revoked all privileges when i was logged in as admin in mysql. and now it says access denied for all operations. how to reset this?

for example,
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'VVVV';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: try this http://hack2live.blogspot.com/2009/04/restore-repair-reset-mysql-root.html

Comment: where to add this file restore_root_privileges.sql?

Comment: anywhere, for example, in your home dir

Comment: when i write the last command grant all .... it says: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: did you restart it ? it shouldn't be running with that option anymore at that point

Comment: thanks man :) you are my savior